# git rebase interactive, cannot merge binary files, error: could not apply

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I created a new repository in my PC, then create file named : foo.txt.
So simply, I added text to foo.txt , and commit it. I make let's say 10 commits, every time I added something.

Now, I deleted foo.txt and create him again and I write only : "ver11" and commit it.

Now, I want all my changes, to be on  the 11 commit. So I write the command:
Git rebase -i some-SHA1

And I pick the last commit and put him between other commits. I save and then I see:

Warning: cannot merge binary files: foo.txt....
Error: could not apply...

So I write the command:
Git mergetool (i use beyondcompare)
And it says: no files need merging.

So, how to solve it?
Also foo.txt, isn't binary! (Encoded in ANSI  in win7 64bit)

Btw, the original problem was: we have two groups which develop same program but with different repositories. So other group make a lot of commits. So I take their directory with the last commit, to my pc. So here was analogy, their project/directory is the 11 commit in my story...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"So I write the command: Git mergetool (i use beyondcompare) And it says: no files need merging." -  there is a bug in git!!! I dont know when it happens, that writing "git mergetool" lie to you "no files need merging".

The solution is to write:
"git mergetool *".

Its strange, but this was the solution for me:)